# Problem regarding Installation of Pillow for PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner at coding and am facing a problem regarding installation of Pillow module. I firstly installed pip from PyCharm itself. Then I installed Pillow from cmd using following code:

python -m pip install pip
and then
python -m pip install Pillow

Both times i got a message Requirement already satisfied. So that means the modules i want to install are already installed on my PC. However when i try to import the module in PyCharm, it gives me a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

when i import

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

What do I do now to use the module in my code?

P.S. The path directory shown in cmd when i install Pillow is actually not available in my PC.

c:/Users/< My name >/appdata/....

There is no folder named 'appdata' in there.

Comment: There is a folder appdata, it is just hidden. Type '%APPDATA%' in the (file) explorer location bar and it will be opened. What happens if you run the python file from the cmd (where you installed the module via pip?). Do you have multiple python installations? Do you use venv?

Comment: I still get the same error ModuleNotFoundError when I run the code in cmd. No, i do not have multiple python installations. I don't exactly know venv is but i do see a folder named venv library root in my project tab in PyCharm.

Comment: Then you are using venv (or PyCharm is), see my answer and mark it as solved if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File > Settings > Project Settings > Project Interpreter > Python Interpreters`

Click on the `+` sign on the right side. set your python path for PyCharm

Comment: You mean I should click on the + sign, select Pillow and install it, right? Over here when I install it, it shows Install packages failed but when I run the code mentioned in question on cmd it shows Requirement already satisfied

Comment: no, you should choose the `python` path that you installed pillow in it .  I suggest create a virtualenv and install pillow and anything you want in it, then do above.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command line, then go to your project directory, then type:

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

to start the activation of the venv (virtual environment which stores its own python installation). Then just install Pillow with pip again

```
pip install Pillow
```

if you have no pip in your venv you need to install it there too: Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

python get-pip.py

or you can just install the Pillow module over PyCharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#