# I have pillow installed and updated, but pycharm does not recognize 'PIL', what to do?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, modulenotfounderror

I'm getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

when using this in code in pycharm:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import image

root = Tk()

root.title('PIL hates me')
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/Cyril/Desktop/it/icon3.ico')

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\Cyril\Desktop\it\Images\Shi.jpg"))
my_label = label(image=my_img).pack

button_quit = Button(root, text= "Exit Program", command=root.quit).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

pip freeze gives me:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.6
image==1.5.33
Pillow==8.3.1
pytz==2021.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

I've tried reinstalling Python to make sure the path thingie box was checked.
I've tried all sorts of code to do basicly the same thing: trying to import from PIL.
When hovering over 'PIL' in pycharm i don't get any tooltip giving me package info, like i get when hovering over 'tkinter'.
This is where the PIL map is located(its the same folder as where tkinter is located):

```
C:\Users\Cyril\anaconda3\Lib\PIL
```

Need some help, because i have no idea what's going wrong...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, you likely have an issue with setting your path correctly in pycharm, try this SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950039/problem-regarding-installation-of-pillow-for-pycharm. Also I think you import as `from PIL import Image` where `Image` is capitalized.

Comment: Also, you see package info for tkinter because it is part of the standard python lib while pillow isn't. This tells me your interpreter is not set to pick up wherever you have pillow installed. I know you're probably looking to resolve this issue quickly, but it would be worth a bit of time to read up on `venv` or `poetry` (my favorite) to help you manage environments much easier/better. https://python-poetry.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot @jclark754, i've tried the suggestions mentioned in the link you've sent, and it worked!